# Composition of derivative of inverse of function with itself proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am currently dealing with a situation where I have to figure out if the following holds. Given
$$
g(x) = \int^x_a\frac{1}{f(u)}du
$$
Prove that:
$$
(g^{-1})' \circ g=f
$$
and that
$$
(g^{-1})'' \circ g=f'f
$$
where $a$ is some arbitrary value and $f$ is a positive function.

I tried figuring out the problem by computing the inverse of $g$ and then taking its derivative, followed by filling in $g$ into the resulting function, but I wasn't able to come up with anything sensible, apart from an ugly formula.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You don't have to compute $g^{-1}$. Use the fact that $(g^{-1})'(x)=\frac 1 {g'(g^{-1}(x))}$. Since $g'(x)=\frac 1 {f(x)}$ both parts follow easily.

Comment: Ah, very nice identity. Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll accept your answer when it allows me to do so.

Comment: Actually, how does it work with taking the second derivative of the inverse. I get stuck with how to handle the $g'(g^{-1}(x))$ part in the derivative. Could you give me another hint for this?

Comment: $(g^{-1})'(g(x)=\frac 1{g' (g^{-1)})(g(x))}=\frac  1{g'(x)}=f(x)$. @CharlieShuffler

Comment: Yeah, I got that one also. I meant the second one in my question, i.e. $(g^{-1})'' \circ g=f'f$. How can I handle the double derivative here? Then I basically need to evaluate $g''(g^{-1}(x))$, but I don't know what identity or trick to use for that.

Comment: @CharlieShuffler By chain rule $(g^{-1}'\circ g)'=(g^{-1}''\circ g) (g')$. Just move $g'$ to the right side.

Comment: @KaboMurhpy Ok, will give it a shot. Thanks for your effort/time!